# Flask integration error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to deploy an ML model using Flask but encountering the above stated error.
The app.py code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/fertility',methods=['GET'])
def fertility():
    return render_template("fertility.html")

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    ans = suppcode1.hello(final_features)
    return render_template("result.html", s=ans)
```

The supporting code for ML model to work on input data:

```
def hello(X_test3):
    data = pd.read_csv('soil_fertility.csv')
    data1 = data.drop(data[data['fertility'] == 2].index)
    df = data1
    X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
    y = df.iloc[:,-1]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=6)

    num_columns = ['N','P','K','ph','ec']
    normalizer = MinMaxScaler()
    normalizer.fit(X_train[num_columns])
    X_train[num_columns] = normalizer.transform(X_train[num_columns])
    filename='fertility_model.pkl'
    loaded_model = clk.load(filename,'rb')

    X_test4 = normalizer.transform(X_test3)

    y_pred3 = loaded_model.predict(X_test4)
    return int(y_pred3)
```

And the HTML code for taking the input and showing the prediction value:

```
        <form action="." method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="N" placeholder="Nitrogen">
        <input type="number" name="P" placeholder="Phosphorus">
        <input type="number" name="K" placeholder="Potassium">
        <input type="number" name="pH" placeholder="pH value">
        <input type="number" name="EC" placeholder="EC value">
        <input class="number" type="submit" value="Check">
        </form>
        <h4 style="text-align: center;">{{ s }}</h4>
```